# wxpython menubar with no dropdown items

Tags: wxpython

I’m using Python 3.7 with wxPython 4.0.4. Having a problem with menuBar when I only want a single clickable item. It’s a menu bar with a menu object appended but no menu items are in the menu object. There is no drop-down and  no id to bind with. The menuBar object eats the onClick event. I just want to detect when the “Run” item is clicked. Is there any way of catching this event?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Without your code to look at, it's impossible to say. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Whilst the real answer should be, add a menu item called `Run` to your `Run` menu, because that enables the user to choose to run the function, rather than accidently running it by clicking on the menubar, the answer is yes you can.

`Bind` to the event `wx.EVT_MENU_OPEN`

```
import wx
import wx.stc
class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = MenuFrame(None, title="Menus and MenuBars")
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        self.frame.Show()

        return True

ID_READ_ONLY = wx.NewId()

class MenuFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MenuFrame, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Attributes
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.txtctrl = wx.stc.StyledTextCtrl(self.panel,
                                   style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)

        # Layout
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(self.txtctrl, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.CreateStatusBar() # For output display

        # Setup the Menu
        menub = wx.MenuBar()

        # File Menu
        filem = wx.Menu()
        filem.Append(wx.ID_NEW, "New")
        filem.Append(wx.ID_OPEN, "Open")
        filem.Append(wx.ID_SAVE, "Save")
        filem.Append(wx.ID_SAVEAS, "Save_As")
        menub.Append(filem, "&File")

        # Edit Menu
        editm = wx.Menu()
        editm.Append(wx.ID_UNDO, "Undo")
        editm.Append(wx.ID_REDO, "Redo")
        editm.Append(wx.ID_COPY, "Copy")
        editm.Append(wx.ID_CUT, "Cut")
        editm.Append(wx.ID_PASTE, "Paste")
        editm.Append(wx.ID_SELECTALL, "SelectAll")
        editm.AppendSeparator()
        editm.Append(ID_READ_ONLY, "Read Only",
                     kind=wx.ITEM_CHECK)
        menub.Append(editm, "Edit")

        # History Menu
        historym = wx.Menu()
        historym.Append(wx.ID_PREVIEW, "Recent")
        menub.Append(historym, "&History")

        # Help Menu
        helpm = wx.Menu()
        helpm.Append(wx.ID_HELP_INDEX, "Hint")
        helpm.Append(wx.ID_ABOUT, "About")
        menub.Append(helpm, "&Help")

        # Run Menu
        runm = wx.Menu()
        menub.Append(runm,"&Run")

        self.SetMenuBar(menub)

        # Event Handlers
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnMenu)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU_OPEN, self.OnMenu)

    def OnMenu(self, event):
        """Handle menu clicks"""
        evt_id = event.GetId()
        if evt_id == 0:
            obj = event.GetMenu()
            if obj.GetTitle() == "&Run":
                self.txtctrl.AddText('Running program\n')
        else:
            self.txtctrl.AddText("Menu item "+str(evt_id)+" selected\n")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp()
    app.MainLoop()
```

You have a choice of:

1. EVT_MENU_OPEN: A menu is about to be opened. On Windows, this is only sent once for each navigation of the menubar (up until all menus have closed).
2. EVT_MENU_CLOSE: A menu has been just closed. Notice that this event
   is currently being sent before the menu selection ( wxEVT_MENU )
   event, if any.
3. EVT_MENU_HIGHLIGHT: The menu item with the specified id has been
   highlighted: used to show help prompts in the status bar by wx.Frame
4. EVT_MENU_HIGHLIGHT_ALL: A menu item has been highlighted, i.e. the
   currently selected menu item has changed.

That said, I still think that you should add a `Run` menu item to the `Run` menu
[image]

Comment: This works but I haven't found a way to prevent the empty submenu from opening or close it when clicked, and an attempted hack to remove or replace the menu in the event crashes the program.

Comment: @dw1 The issue is really that you want a Cat to bark or a `menu` to act, just for a single entry, as a `toolbar`. Perhaps adding a `title` to the menu will make it look a little better, rather than having it blank. i.e. `runm = wx.Menu("Run Instantly")`